# What is "chopsing the ref"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang

Adam Jones, the Wales and Lions prop, was reported as saying about his policy regarding the referee before yesterday's match:-

> You have to get the ref on the right side of you. You don't want to be
>   in their face, **chopsing** at them, getting on their nerves and
>   pissing them off...

*Chopsing* is a new word to me. Looking it up, the only definition I can find is on the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chopsing):-

> 'Chopsing' is a Welsh slang term for arguing or saying disrespectful
>   things to someone.

This seems quite an apposite definition, and works well given the context, but is there a more reliable source for this word? Are there any clues as to the etymology?

Comment: A British slang collection has: "chopsy  Adj. 1. Chatty. [Welsh/Stoke use]
2. Moody, annoyed." (http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/c.htm)

Comment: Then there's "busting someone's chops," which has to do with harassing someone unnecessarily.  How exercising one's own jaws in a derogatory or harassing manner involves breaking or busting another person's jaws is a kind of mystery to me, but then sayings do not always make sense.  I suppose words, on the other hand, can inflict psychological damage on another person, so the breaking of jaws with one's words is metaphorical for doing psychological damage.  Personally, the saying is one of my faves!  "Hey, stop busting my chops, will ya?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED has this definition (sense 8) for **chop**...

> trans. To exchange or bandy words; esp. in *to chop logic*;
>    to exchange logical arguments and terms, bandy logic, reason argumentatively, argue.
>   (In late use, often erroneously referred to *chop* sense 1, as if *to mince, divide minutely, split hairs, or hash up.*)

So etymologically it's not related to ***chop*** (usually pl. *Jaws; sides of the face*), which is from [chap](http://define.com/chap). Nor is it very closely related to *chop = cut up*, as OED points out above.

---

Regardless of whether the variant *chopsy* derives from the "bandy words" or "mouth/jaw" sense, there seems no doubt it's originally/primarily Welsh. Here's an early instance from Welsh Author Ron Berry in [The Full-time Amateur (1966)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=K04JAQAAIAAJ&q=chopsy&dq=chopsy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7p_RUcfvKeqG0AW6yYGwCA&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBQ)...

> "Just let him know ... and don't be so bloody chopsy, ah, if you don't mind?"

Julie Coleman in [The Life of Slang (2012)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vcrb23hxh8gC&pg=PA232&dq=chopsy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GJ7RUdq5GqO_0QW4oICoCQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=chopsy&f=false) includes *chopsy* in a list of "slang terms originating or chiefly used in Wales", and [this website](http://www.pembrokeshirecoast.org.uk/?PID=218) locates it even more precisely in South Pembrokeshire (the South-Western tip of Wales).

Answer (score 3):

Since "chops" can be slang for "mouth" (see [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chops)), it makes sense that "chopsing at" would be synonymous with "mouthing at."

Comment: If by 'mouthing at' you mean 'mouthing off at', you are correct. Someone who is _chopsy_ is impertinent and argumentative. _Chopsing_ is the verb.